# Funcion fork() en for

Tags: c, bucle-for, proceso

¿como funcionaria este codigo? entiendo el proceso de crear hijos, pero no me queda claro cuando hay un for, ¿como seria el conteo de padres e hijos?.

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
 fork();
 printf("process");
}
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función fork como tal crea padre e hijo a la vez. Esto quiere decir que al repetirlo 3 veces creas varios padres y varios hijos. Pondré los hijos y padres por cada ciclo.

```
Primer ciclo:      Padres
                  1° Hijo
```

Para el segundo ciclo el padre crea otro 2° hijo, pero el 1° hijo se vuelve 2° padre y a su vez crea otro 3° hijo.

```
Segundo ciclo:     Padre ---> 2° Hijo
                   2° Padre
                   3° Hijo
```

Ahora para el tercer ciclo el Padre crea otro 4° hijo y el 2° padre crea otro 5° hijo. No nos olvidemos que los 2° hijo y 3° hijo ahora se vuelven 3° padre y 4° padre que a su vez crean otros 6° hijo y 7° hijo. Dejando algo como lo siguiente:

```
Tercer ciclo: 4° Hijo<--- Padre ---> 3° Padre ---> 6° Hijo
                         2° Padre---> 5° Hijo
                         4° Padre
                         7° Hijo
```

En si esto es exponencial, es decir, 2^n por cada fork().

Comment: Como tal la función fork() crea varios padres y varios hijos, los hijos se convierten en padres por cada ciclo y a su vez crean su propio hijo. En linux es más sencillo ver esto ya que cada padre y cada hijo le corresponde un ID propio, pero consecutivos, algo como tipo ID: 345 del padre y el hijo tiene ID: 346.

Comment: Entendi, muchas gracias. Pero lo que no me queda claro es porque si son 8 procesos, el printf me imprime 11 veces...¿Me podrias explicar si no es mucha molestia?

Comment: En qué sistema haces los fork()? En linux o windows, creo que en windows tiene un error en algunas IDES, bueno al menos eso observe al realizarlo en windows. Pruebe en lugar de for un ciclo while

Comment: Mi SO principal es W7. Estoy ejecutando lubuntu en una maquina virtual, aqui es donde hago los fork().

Comment: te paso el codigo.  edit: es un while comun jaja, no puedo pasar el codigo

Comment: Bien,intentaré probar el código que publicaste y probaré

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Bien por suerte tenía algo de procesos y te explico. Ves 11 veces los print("process"); debido a que cada proceso necesita de un tiempo para su creación y al ponerlo en un bucle este lo crea tan rápido que crea datos basura.                                                                                                                printf("Hijo:%d  Padre:%d\n",getpid(),getppid());                                                      Prueba con la línea de código para imprimir, te dará el ID que mencione antes y verás que habrá algunas que se repiten.

Comment: Ah listo gracias, entonces cuando esta en un ciclo tambien hace 2**n por cada fork, si hay dos fork() sigo la misma logica. Corrigeme si me equivoco. Originalmente me quedo con 8 procesos en mi problema.

Comment: Efectivamente, manejas 2^n  por cada ciclo

Comment: Gracias, me ayudaste mucho!